# Is there predefined NSColor for the Dock and Menubar on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uikit, appkit

There are some `NSColor` initialization helpers like `controlColor()` which return various colors of system components. Is there any such thing for the dock and menubar? I couldn't see one by name that popped out. If there is no such helper, is there another way to get the color?

I want to use it as the default `NSWindow` background color for a utility application I am developing that will be displayed in a small, borderless `NSWindow`.

They are both controlled from the 'General' panel in 'System Preferences' shown in the figure below.

[image: System Preferences Dialog]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure but it looks it is not there in NSColor. For utility you can use HUD type of NSPanel with black background, isn't it?

Comment: @Anoop - Thank you - this is a very helpful answer, although not a working one in my particular case. It is very good to know about, and I did not know about it before so thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the menu bar and Dock background appearances aren't `NSColor` system colors. They do look a lot like the Dark Vibrant and Light Vibrant styles you can get from [`NSVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSVisualEffectView_Class/index.html), though.

If you want to change your view's appearance to match the state of the "Use dark menu bar and Dock" preference... well, there's no API for that, but you can read that preference from where it's stored. (Since it's not API, caveat emptor: there's no guarantee the preference storage won't change in later OS X versions.)

In Swift (and broken into several lines for clarity):

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let globalPrefs = defaults.persistentDomainForName(NSGlobalDomain)!
let interfaceStyle = globalPrefs["AppleInterfaceStyle"]
if interfaceStyle as! String == "Dark" {
    // time to be all emo
}
```